# How to activate a conda virtualenv in a Jupyter Notebook terminal?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

In a Jupyter Notebook terminal (used from a browser) I created a new `conda` environment. But when I tried to activate it using:

```
source activate <env_name>
```

But I got following error:

> /bin/sh: 5: source: not found

I also tried:

```
activate <env_name>
```

and

```
conda activate <env_name>
```

but both of these approaches haven't worked. I'm using `Anaconda 3` on

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Release:        16.04 
Codename:       xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way (your conda.sh could be in a different path).
In the same jupyter cell, paste this:

```
%%bash
source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate <your_environment_name>
```